# Wscript.Echo vs print в JScript

Tags: windows, jscript

Как я понимаю, есть вариант интерпретатора JScript - выполнение с помощью, скажем, `cscript.exe`, а есть возможность компиляции с помощью `jsc.exe`. Я пока не вдаюсь в серьезные вещи, достаточно азов. Но сразу столкнулся с тем, что в одном варианте вывод выполняется через `WScript.Echo` и не иначе, а во втором - через `print`.

А как-то скрестить можно? Как вообще получать скрипты, которые будут и интерпретироваться, и компилироваться? Какой у них общий знаменатель?

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы путаетесь в понятиях. JScript - это скриптовый язык поддержка которого встроена в операционные системы WIndows. И выполнить код на этом языке можно с помощью интерпретатора cscript.exe. А ещё имеется JScript.NET - язык программирования, который хоть и является следующим шагом в развитии от JScript. Но является другим языком с доступом к среде .Net Framework. Его код и можно скомпилировать с помощью jsc.exe. Это схожие, но разные вещи. Вы определитесь для чего нужен инструмент, а потом у же выбирайте соответствующий. Сформулируйте вопрос: "зачем",получите ответ точнее.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Возможно. Я с ним столкнулся только сейчас первый раз. У малого d школе информатика на хрен каком уровне. Меня не устраивает. По ряду причин я выбрал для него Jscript - по каким, давайте не будем, потому что кроме как к holy wars это ни к чему не приведет. Понятно, что первое, что нужно - вывод на экран, без этого же никак. И тут я сталкиваюсь в Интернете с двумя версиями - одни пишут print, другие WScript.Echo. Вы своим комментарием пояснили мне, в чем разница - что это 2 разных языка. Спасибо, найти это ясно и недвусмысленно в Интернете я не смог. Если подскажете еще, что

Comment: @Daemon-5 малому почитать - буду признателен. Ориентируемся тогда на некомпилируемую версию - залазить в .NET ему явно рановато :)

Comment: Тогда ищите книги типа "программирование Windows Script Host". Но, по хорошему, уже следовало бы тогда приступать к изучению Powershell - это современный (т.е .поддерживаемый производителем) скриптовый язык. Предполагалось, что он заменит и Batch, и WHS в современных Windows OS. И это совет без всяких холиворов. Хотя если ребенок не такой уж взрослый, то и первое сойдет! Дело в том, что в WHS  - кроме JScript, есть поддержка VBscript - очень простой и доступный для изучения язык.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Есть пара ограничений - надо что-то как можно проще, и чтоб я сам в нем разбирался :), а PowerShell как минимум второму условию не отвечает. Кроме того, в данном случае привлекает простота, определенная С-подобность - чтоб потом было проще перейти к серьезным вещам, отсутствие компиляторов и т.п. маеты. Сделал, запустил, посмотрел... Пацан в 8 классе. Вроде бы и не такой уж маленький, но как-то уж очень у них в школе было запущено с информатикой, так что он ее просто боится и не любит :(